# Source content DB Size after moving site collections

Tags: 2010, powershell, site-collection, content-database, move

I have one content DB (Source content DB) with 500+ site collections in it. Recently i have moved all site collections to 10 different content DBs (using `Move-SPSite` command) in order to improve performance. My question is: What the command `Move-SPSite` actually does?

1. Will it copy the site collections to destination DB or migrate? because after Moving site collections, when i go into source content DB in `dbo.AllWebs` table, i can still see all the site collections there. How can we reduce the size of source content DB after moving?
2. Is `Move-SPSite` command reduces size on source content DB?
3. Whats is shrinking? what its benefit and how can we shrink source DB using powershell?
4. After Move operation, if i create new site collection, where it will go? in old source content DB or in newly created content DB?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you run Move-SPSite, the site collection gets moved to the new content database.However, the site collection in the source Content Database was not completely removed. The site collection "Deleted" flag was set to 1. This means it is scheduled for deletion. The Gradual site delete timer jobs will delete the site collection from the content database. By default, this timer job runs once a day. To ensure the site is completely deleted, run the timer job. [Error using Move-SPSite cmdlet](http://sharepointrelated.com/tag/move-spsite/)
2. it reduce the size yes and No. Yes mean when you move a site collection, it will free the space in Database but this will not reduce the size of DB. You will see more free space in DB.
3. Shrinking means, when you have more free /white /unused space in your database then this process remove that space and reduce the size of DB. i.e you have db with 100GB of Size with 50GB free space. On disk its size is 100Gb but after shrink it will go down to around 60GB.
4. its depend, typically sharepoint provision the site in a DB which has less number of sites. But you can control where it goes by provisioning the site via Powershell, or by setting your content databases to Stopped in central admin (or even further by adjusting the max number of sites each db can contain)

Comment: To point 4, you can control where it goes by provisioning the site via Powershell, or by setting your content databases to Stopped in central admin (or even further by adjusting the max number of sites each db can contain)